# "Me too invited" Is this correct?

Tags: word-usage

A friend of mine recently got invited to a speech given by Barack Obama on his trip to Brussels. She wrote "Me too invited" on her Facebook profile. I told her it sounded pidgin. She didn't seem to agree. As I am not a native English speaker, I couldn't really explain why I thought it was shaky, only saying that I felt that way. I suggested "I'm invited too" or the use of a coma "Me too, invited." Did I, as she suggested, sound like a complete fool?

Comment: You are correct. "Me too invited" sounds like something (charming) that an English language learner would say. Speaking of such, we have a sister site for learners' (of all levels) questions. Tell her about it! ;) It's [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You are right to doubt the correctness. @oerkelens explains a potential route your friend reached her phrase, but as plain English, it sucks. She is the subject of the invitation, so the correct pronoun for her to use is 'I' ('me' is for when she is the object). Too is also primarily used at the end of a sentence, because it is a short way of indicating that what has just been detailed happened at some other time/place to someone else too. It is equivalent in most usages to 'as well.' Better constructions include:

> I too am invited
>
> I'm invited too
>
> I'm also invited
>
> I got/received/was given an invite (too)
>
> [person_name] invited me too <-- note, me because she is now the object

Answer (score 0):

On several social media and in different forms of (short) message exchange, this form of English is very common.
I agree that outside those specific environments, sentences like these are to be avoided because they are ungrammatical. But *within* those environments, they are a normal part of the dialect and register, so criticizing them there is probably not a very useful or rewarding expenditure of time...

Starting sentences with *me* may have it's origin in the < me>, [me] or */me* tags that are, or at some point were, implemented on several on-line communication platforms.
They were short for *username*, and often (as on IRC) would effectively substitute the username.

Hence, one would write:

> /me is happy too

and the other participant in the conversation would see:

> *oerkelens is happy too*

With the demise of verbs in short messaging, this became "/me happy too", or "me happy too".

I would simply accept "me too happy" as just one step further down this, arguably deplorable, road towards oversimplification.

Comment: I wonder if the downvoter can substantiate any factual error in this answer, or if they just want to anonymously disagree with my assertion that language is used in certain ways on-line?